# PIL doesn't show up in Pycharm or in Python 3.4.3 shell...but works in my command line

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, pycharm

Im trying to work on some code which includes PIL. I want to do it on my PyCharm 4.5.3 version, but PIL wont import. It's not being recognized, or in other words, `ImportError: No module named 'PIL'`. Its strange because it is in my site-packages. I have it installed through Pillow, as you can see in my list of packages.

```
(MYVirtualEnv) C:\Users\Jay_000\siteProject\PROJECTone> pip freeze
blinker==1.4
Django==1.8
django-appconf==1.0.1
django-bootstrap-markdown==1.8.1
django-disqus==0.5
django-extensions==1.5.5
django-imagekit==3.2.6
django-markdown==0.8.4
django-mptt==0.7.4
django-pagedown==0.1.0
django-staticblog==0.2.5
django-tinymce==1.5.3
django-wpadmin==1.7.4
docutils==0.12
feedgenerator==1.7
feedparser==5.2.0
html2text==2015.6.21
Jinja2==2.8
Markdown==2.6.2
MarkupSafe==0.23
mistune==0.7
mock==1.2.0
pbr==1.3.0
pelican==3.6.2
pilkit==1.1.12
Pillow==2.9.0
Pygments==2.0.2
python-dateutil==2.4.2
pytz==2015.4
PyYAML==3.11
six==1.9.0
slugify==0.0.1
Unidecode==0.4.18
xmltodict==0.9.2
```

Its strange, because in my command line the code works. I can import PIL without an issue, but in Pycharm and Python shell, it doesn't work. I even installed Pillow on Pycharm (*not sure why I even need to install some of these packages again with this software, but that's a diff issue for now*) and PIL still wont import. I try to install PIL on Pycharm and it wont even install, but I suppose thats what led to Pillow's existence. Either way, I dont know whats up with this thing. Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: Is Pycharm using `MYVirtualEnv` or your system installation of Python?

Comment: hmm I never considered that. It would make sense as to why I would have to re-install some of these packages. Im going to check, but I think its on the system installation of Python

Comment: Turns out it was on the system installation of Python. I made the switch, but it still didnt work until I simply restarted the program. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: do you know why `pip freeze` shows nothing for me?

Answer (score 1):

**Found the solution to my problem.**

Brobin helped me realize that Pycharm may be running on a different python environment, which makes sense as to why I had to re-install some programs. With that thought, I made the switch to my virtual environment, but I still had no progress, until I simply decided to restart Pycharm. Now it works: PIL imports to my Pycharm.